# Radon-Nikodym's theorem both measures should be σ-finites?

Tags: measure-theory

Radon-Nikodym's theorem  both measures should be σ-finites? 
Radon-Nikodym's theorem  both measures should be σ-finites?

Comment: In the classical version, yes. The assumption can be weakened though.

Comment: Both could be no σ-finites?

Comment: You wan to know what the most general form of the result is? You can find it [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372178).